# putExtras(child class) - receiving base class

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I've got **class Playlist extends ArrayList** I use in

```
Playlist playlist = new Playlist(); 
intent.putExtra("playlist", playlist);
```

and then I try to get it back:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("playlist")) {
    playlist = (Playlist)(getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("playlist"));
}
```

but I receive an error: 
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to pl.mal.player.Playlist.**
I know that to problem is I would like to cast base class to child class. But I do not know how to avoid it in this example. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getStringArrayList` can't return you a `Playlist` Object. You will have to do something like

```
List<String> list = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("playlist");
Playlist playlist = new Playlist();
playlist.addAll(list);
```

You can only cast an object to super classes & interfaces implemented by the concrete runtime type. That's `ArrayList` in this case. If you wanted to change that you'd have to modify the `getStringArrayList` method because something in there says explicitly `new ArrayList`

Comment: During this time I found similar solution - overriding a constructor so it can get an arraylist. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your playlist class will have to implement parcelable to pass it in an extra.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

[How can I make my custom objects Parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-be-parcelable)

Comment: That might not work for classes that inherit from `ArrayList` - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3847